# Trying to pass the user type in a condition laravel

Tags: php, logical-operators

When I grab the current user (who is a manager) like so:

```
$user = Auth::user()->user_role;
```

I then die and dump this:

```
dd($user);
```

This displays

```
string(7) "Manager"
```

I then want to use a conditional to check if it is a specific user:

```
dd($user == ("Admin" || "Superuser"));
```

This (for some reason) returns true:

```
bool(true)
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be written as ...

```
dd($user === "Admin" || $user === "Superuser");
```

... instead. There are two separate conditions that should be checked separately.

As about the current situation, it's... funny. See, `||` operator in PHP doesn't work like in JavaScript (where it returns either first operand, if it evaluates to `truthy` value, or the second operand *without changing their types*).

But it's PHP, and here the result of `||` operation is *always* a `boolean` value - either `true` or `false`. It's no surprise that it's `true` in this case, as only two string values in PHP are considered `falsy` - an empty string and `'0'`. The first operand of `'Admin' || 'Superuser'` is neither, so this expression evaluates to `true`.

So it becomes...

```
dd($user == true);
```

Again, with proper comparison operator - `===` - you should've noticed the difference here. But it's `==`, so it converts its operands' types before actually comparing them.

By the rules of type coercing (which are described quite nicely in the [**docpage**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)), when one value of the comparison is `boolean`, the other *always* gets converted to `boolean` too. As `$user` isn't either `''` or `'0'`, it gets converted to `true` too.

So it finally becomes this:

```
dd(true === true);
```

Guess what's the result? )

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using type comparison (`===` vs `==`) or maybe just: `dd(in_array($user, array("Admin", "Superuser")));`?

What you're doing is basically "$user is not empty, and neither is 'admin' or 'superuser'"

Answer (score 0):

`("Admin" || "Superuser")`

is evaluated first (parenthesis) and that equals `true`.  What you really want is probably:

`dd($user == "Admin" || $user == "Superuser");`